# Java / Vaadin Image Upload Thumbnail

Tags: java, vaadin

I would like to ask how to show the Thumbnail after selecting the file. Instead showing the image after clicking the Upload button

```
            image.setVisible(false);


        @Override
        public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event) {
            // Show the uploaded file in the image viewer
            FileResource resource = new FileResource(file);
            image.setVisible(true);
            image.setSource(resource);
            image.setHeight("200");
            image.setWidth("200");


            List<MenuItem> items = getSettings().getItems();
            items.stream().forEach((item) -> {
                item.setIcon(resource);
            });
        }


    }

    ImageReceiver receiver = new ImageReceiver(); 

    // Create the upload with a caption and set receiver later
    final Upload upload = new Upload("",receiver);
    upload.setButtonCaption("Select a File");
    upload.addSucceededListener(receiver);
    root.addComponent(upload);
```

Thank you in advance .

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: After receiving the upload you have to store the image server side and then add a image component to your vaadin ui

Comment: @AndréSchild , no offence, but why do you always comment instead of posting the answer?

Comment: @kukis Very short answers (which only points the user in the correct direction) are for me not full answers. A real answer would include some code or more infos from my side.